# Score in replay missions

Tags: frozen-synapse

Can I improve my campaign mission score by replaying them? I recieved a gold medal on a replay, but it did not seem to register.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I have also replayed a campaign mission, and the High score and Best Medal did not register after the replay.

In the Campaign, there is a button for "Play Unlocked Missions". For each of the completed missions you **should** see a list of Played Seeds, as well as a High score and Best Medal for each replay. **However**, in my experience, there have been a number of times when only the *first* playthrough registered in this list, and a few times when *none* of the playthroughs registered in this list.

This appears to be buggy or inconsistent behavior of the game. After attempting to diagnose the problem *(by quitting a mission halfway through, exiting the game suddenly during a mission, and fully completing a mission)*, whether a replay shows up or not in the list of Played Seeds was still inconsistent.

**This applies to the Offline Campaign for the May 2012 edition of Frozen Synapse.**